# Redux store is set to default value, when we refresh the page

Tags: redux

I was working on a project where I was seeing that the likes array consists of authenticated user id or not?
**likes.includes(authenticatedUser._id)**
This authenticatedUser is state inside our redux store. Now when I refresh the page the redux store authenticatedUser state is automatically set to default value. Due to this, it is showing error **authenticatedUser._id** is not defined. Is there any way to prevent the redux store set to null when we refresh the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redux store is not persistent, so what you are observing is expected behavior.

There are several ways to combat that problem:

- check if `authenticatedUser` exists before accessing it
- synchronizing parts of the store to a more persistent storage location and restoring it on page load. The persistent storage I would recommend is *localStorage* or *cookies*.

Comment: I was thinking that on page load I will store the authenticated user details in local storage and before executing this authenticatedUser._id, I will instead of fetching authenticated user details from redux store, I will fetch authenticated user from local storage. Please tell me is it correct way or not?

Comment: Or I was thinking that Just before page reload i will store the authenticated user details to local storage and just after page reload i will fetch authenticated user data from local storage and dispatch to redux store.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can provide you with a "correct way". There is many ways to achieve that and which one you should choose depends on your project and how it integrates best with the rest of your code. But it might be benefitial to research existing libraries, because I am sure you are not the first person to stumble across that problem.